# How can I get the generic constraints from CodeInterface as a CodeType object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-generation, envdte

I am using [DTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio 2010 to examine C# classes and automatically generate code.

When I encounter a class that implements a generic interface, I want to access the type constraint as a `CodeType` object.

example:

```
class ServiceProviderCollection : IList<IServiceProvider> {}
```

I have the `CodeClass` object that represents `ServiceProviderCollection`. I can obtain the `CodeInterface` object for `IList<IServiceProvider>` by using `CodeClass.ImplementedInterfaces`. But I don't know how to get from there to a `CodeInterface` object that represents `IServiceProvider`.

I can find the **name** of the type constraint by parsing CodeInterface.FullName and grabbing the string between the < and >, but this is not sufficient.

I'm using C# to implement this, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Microsoft is focusing on [Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/05/announcing-microsoft-roslyn-june-2012-ctp.aspx) to completely replace this model, parsing the `FullName` may be the only way of doing this.